# How to avoid apps being re-arranged when synching with iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios

I very rarely synchronise my iPhone with iTunes. Because every time I do it all apps are re-arranged on the phone to like they were at the time of my last synching.

Apps that I deleted on the iPhone are transferred to it and folders and location of the icons are out of my preferred order.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable App syncing completely on the apps tab. Then iTunes will not sync the apps anymore and so it won't re-arrange them.
The drawback is that new apps won't be downloaded to your Mac/PC anymore. So in case you have to restore your iPhone using iTunes you will have to re-download all the apps. But as your purchases are connected to your Apple ID you will not loose the apps. They're just not stored on your Mac/PC.

Comment: That's it. I have disabled App syncing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your iPhone to your computer and run iTunes, click on your iPhone under Devices on the left. Then click on Apps in the tabs across the top. This will show you the various screens of apps on your iPhone and also show you a list of all apps installed as a scrolling list.

You can check and uncheck the apps you want to sync over to the iPhone in the scrolling list, you can move the apps into the arrangement you want on the virtual screens.

When everything is as you want it, click Sync in the lower right of iTunes.

You shouldn't have to do this ever time (I don't) and things should stay about the same now. As you add new apps on the iPhone, however, they'll go to the last screen by default. You will still need to drag them where you want them after they download.

Comment: I knew that before. Thanks anyway. But the problem is that exactly THIS is annoying me very much. If I do what you describe above and then synch the iPhone the apps on my iPhone and in iTunes are identical. Then, I use the iPhone. I install a number of apps, i re-arrange apps on the iPhone, I delete a number of apps on the iPhone. Thus, the apps on the iPhone and in iTunes some day look very different. If i know pluf the iPhone into my PC and  if I synch with iTunes, iTunes starts making the iPhone apps look like the old setting in iTunes. it transfers those I deleted, it shifts the icons ...